# How do I create an object of MessageBox in Wpf Automation UI for unit testing

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, wpftoolkit

`Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox msgBox = wpfApp.MainWindow.Find.ByName<Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox>("MsgBox");`

Here it shows an error

> "The type 'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the  generic type or method 'ArtOfTest.WebAii.Silverlight.VisualFind.ByName(string)'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox' to            'ArtOfTest.WebAii.Controls.Xaml.IFrameworkElement'."

in UnitTest.

Comment: Because `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox` doesn't implement `ArtOfTest.WebAii.Controls.Xaml.IFrameworkElement`. You'd need to create a wrapper around the MessageBox, as you cannot modify the given MessageBox class.

Comment: How to Create Wrapper Class for Message Box ?